# Excel: Adding only if there is a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am adding T thru X each cell can be entered with a value of 20%. But I need to subtract from the total of 100%.

Column Z adds Column S and Column Y.

What I want to accomplish is that I want it to subtract as shown in the image. BUT if the values are 0% or blank, I want the "answer" to also be 0, so it will not add with the values in S (if there are values there).

The total Compliance % in column Z should not go over 100%.

I'm not sure where to do the formula or how to put the formula so it calculates correctly

Any help is appreciated :D

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here in your col Y

```
=iferror(1/(1-sum(t25:x25))^-1,0)
```

Comment: This works! But how do I do it, if for example, on the first row S has 75% and there is nothing on Y, I don't want it to turn into 175%. Is it possible to no count the 100% if there is nothing to add?

Comment: I remember `Column Z adds Column S and Column Y. total Compliance % in column Z should not go over 100%.`   Z=S+Y, now S is .75  Y is  0,  Z is .75  < 1.

Comment: there are kinds of solutions as long as you have clear rule,.eg  in Z25` = max(S25,Y25)` take the max value of S and Y when both have values.  Or `=if((S25+Y25)>1,1,S25+Y25)` means if Z is bigger than 1, take it as 100%, otherwise, keep s+y